# How to return from a promise inside then block?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to understand how `promise`'s cascading properly works. For this, I  created a function which returns a new `Promise` but has some `callback functions` in their scope:

```
exports.function1 = (params) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do something sync

    someFunctionAsyncWithCallback(params, (err, data) => { //async func
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(data);
    })
  }).then(data => {
     // do something sync again

    anotherAsyncFunctionWithCallback(data, function (err, response) {
      return err ? Promise.reject(err) : Promise.resolve(response);
      // return err ? reject(err) : resolve(response); ?
    });
  })
}
```

Inside `then` block, how can I made a properly `return` in order to continue cascading process? In `executor` there are resolve/reject functions which I can call in order to continue chaining. But, once we are in `then` execution, these function aren't there - correct me if I'm wrong - and I don't know how to move on.

Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: Just call another function from inside then() which cascades with resolve, reject??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid combining promise chains with callback-style APIs. Instead, wrap the callback-style API with a promise wrapper, which then lets you compose things reasonably.

The examples you've quoted look like NodeJS APIs. If you're using Node, v8 and higher have [`utils.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) which can be used to quickly and easily wrap standard NodeJS-callback-style functions to functions returning promises.

```
// Get promise-enabled versions:
const promiseSomeFunctionAsyncWithCallback = utils.promisify(someFunctionAsyncWithCallback);
const promiseAnotherAsyncFunctionWithCallback = utils.promisify(anotherAsyncFunctionWithCallback);

// Use them:
exports.function1 = (params) => {
  return promiseSomeFunctionAsyncWithCallback(params)
    .then(promiseAnotherAsyncFunctionWithCallback);
  })
};
```

If you're not using Node, or you're using an old version, there's nothing magic about `utils.promisify`, you can easily roll your own:

```
const promisify = f => return function(..args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        f.call(this, ...args, (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

---

Re your comment:

> I have some sync code between these callback functions.. How would you handle it in your first example?

There are two styles for that:

1. Put the sync code in the `then` callback and chain only when you reach your next async bit:

```
exports.function1 = (params) => {
  // Code here will run synchronously when `function1` is called
  return promiseSomeFunctionAsyncWithCallback(params)
    .then(result => {
        // You culd have synchronous code here, which runs when
        // this `then` handler is called and before we wait for the following:
        return promiseAnotherAsyncFunctionWithCallback(result);
    });
  })
};
```

2. Put the sync code in its own `then` callback:

```
exports.function1 = (params) => {
  // Code here will run synchronously when `function1` is called
  return promiseSomeFunctionAsyncWithCallback(params)
    .then(result => {
        // You culd have synchronous code here, which runs when
        // this `then` handler is called.
        // Pass on the result:
        return result;
    })
    .then(promiseAnotherAsyncFunctionWithCallback);
  })
};
```

One advantage to #2 is that each distinct logical step is its own block. It does mean one additional yield back to the microtask loop at the end of this iteration of the main event loop, but that's not likely to be an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm actually using node 7.10 and `promisifying` using `bluebird`. Look, I have some sync code between these callback functions.. How would you handle it in your first example?

Comment: I didn't know `then()` clause can return a value instead of a Promise. Reading [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) now this are clearly saying `if the handler function: returns a value, the promise returned by then gets resolved with the returned value as its value.`. Thank you for point it out

Comment: @guijob: :-) Not only *can* a `then` handler return a non-promise value, it's quite common that it does. :-) (`then`, itself, always returns  apromise though; what the `then` handler returns just determines how that promise is settled.)

Comment: Cool, I've just started using promises, that's why I have no notion about some common approaches, but I'm working it out. Could you answer one last doubt about your resolution? All sync code running when func1 is called, but before returning first promise, must not throw an exception, right? What if it does? My function will still return a reject promise?

Comment: @guijob: No, if it throws in that initial section, there's nothing to convert it to a rejection instead. If you want to do that, probably the simplest thing is `return Promise.resolve().then(() => { /*...sync code...*/}).then(() => promiseSomeFunctionAsyncWithCallback(params)).then(promiseAnotherAsyncFunctionWithCallback);`. The sync code there won't run until the microtask loop at the end of the current event loop, and any exceptions it throws will become rejections.

Comment: @guijob: You might also look at [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), an ES2017+ feature (supported in current Chrome, Firefox and Edge) which make a lot of this (though not all of it) more straight-forward.  They're syntactic sugar on promises. But, you know, the good kind of sugar.

Answer (score 3):

You need to return another Promise:

```
return new Promise((res, rej) => anotherAsyncFunctionWithCallback(data, (err, data) => err ? rej(err) : res(data));
```

However then it would make sense to promisify the function:

```
 const promisify = f => (...args) => new Promise((res, rej) => f(...args, (err, data) => err? rej(err) : res(data)));

const asyncF = promisify(AsyncFunctionWithCallback);
```

So one can do:

```
asyncF(1).then(asyncF).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a flag variable for returning something.

example;

```
async function test(){
   let flag=0;
   await fetch(request).then(()=> flag=1}
   if(flag==1) return;
}
```