# Promise.resolve() isn't being executed

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to save a brand new object into my database but only if it doesn't exists yet. For this, I created this method in other to make two validations: (1) if object is missing and (2) if object already exists. If everything is ok, then save. Code is below:

```
exports.new = (obj) => {
  return Promise.resolve(() => {
    if (!obj) throw Error('object is missing');

    this.getOneAsync(obj).then(repeatedObj => {
      if (repeatedObj.length != 0) throw Error('Object already saved!');
      return obj;
    });
  }).then(obj => {
    var newObj = createModel(obj);

    return newObj.saveAsync();
  })
};
```

Unfortunately, `Promise.resolve()` aren't being executed. My code jump straight to `then()` clause and `obj` isn't what I expected, always returning `{ length: 0, name: '' }`.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Promise.resolve()` **is** executed, but not the function you pass to it. `Promise.resolve` immediately resolves the promise with the value you pass to it. So `.then` is called with the function you pass to `Promise.resolve`. You don't want to use `Promise.resolve` here.

Comment: You are missing a return before `this.getOneAsync` right now your first function returns undefined.

Comment: `Promise.resolve` does not take a callback.

Comment: in effect, the value you are resolving is the function - a function being an object, `Promise.resolve(object)` - in this case resolves to the (not executed) `function` -oops, I see that's been said already :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Promise.resolve()` **is** executed, but not the function you pass to it. `Promise.resolve` immediately resolves the promise with the value you pass to it. It does not call the function. `.then` is called with the function you pass to `Promise.resolve`.

`Promise.resolve` is not useful in your case. Instead do something like

```
exports.new = (obj) => {
  if (!obj) return Promise.reject(new Error('object is missing'));

  return this.getOneAsync(obj)
    .then(repeatedObj => {
      if (repeatedObj.length != 0) throw Error('Object already saved!');
      var newObj = createModel(obj);
      return newObj.saveAsync();
    });
};
```

Comment: Don't you need to `return Promise.reject(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

After clarifications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48867510/6351322), this way works using `Promise.resolve()`:

```
exports.new = (obj) => {
  return Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    if (!obj) throw Error('object is missing');

    this.getOneAsync(obj).then(repeatedObj => {
      if (repeatedObj.length != 0) throw Error('Object already saved!');
      return obj;
    });
  }).then(obj => {
    var newObj = createModel(obj);

    return newObj.saveAsync();
  })
};
```